# using Map Service or Feature Service for Feature Layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Both, Dynamic Map Services and Feature Services allow for querying data (through FeatureLayer) and bringing FeatureSets to the browser.

Which of the above would yield better performance at querying attributes and geometries of large datasets?